# Jquery Validation Problem

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

The following works. But I need to add the greaterThan attribute to another element. When I add it to a second element, it fails. I see no error but all Jquery UI's break. any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", function (value, element, params) {

        if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
            return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
        }
        return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) || (parseFloat(value) > parseFloat($(params).val()));
    }, 'Start Date must be greater than End Date.');

    $("#EndDate").rules('add', { greaterThan: "#StartDate" });
    $("#EndDate").validate();

});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's *not* working? Also, `.validate` must be called on a `form` element.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the same code on two separate pages. I simply separated them into separate js files.